# extract strings from files using regex with python

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract specific parts of txt-files with python.

Here is my code:

```
import re 
with open('test1.txt') as test_text:
   data = test_text.read()
   wanted_match = re.findall('start(\n.*?)+?end', data)
   wanted_match_str = ",".join(wanted_match)
with open("output.txt", "w") as output:
output.write(wanted_match_str)
```

My txt-files look like this (includes newlines):

blablabla
start blobloblobloblo
bloblo 
blobloblo
end
bla
blablabla
start blobloblobloblo
bloblo 
blobloblo
end
bla
blablabla

and so on. I want to extract only the bloblob parts of the text and write them to a file (and not the blabla parts).
According to pythex my regex should work (http://pythex.org), but all I get as my output is a list of commas. 
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance!
majee

Comment: @PavneetSingh: No, simply `(?s)start(.*?)end`

Comment: the texts include newlines, so simply start(.*?)+?end doesn't work.

Comment: the code now gives me the whole text as output and not just the blob-parts.

Comment: The following modification worked: wanted_match = re.findall('start.*?end', data, re.DOTALL)

Comment: It is exactly the same, just the delimiters are now part of the output.